# Create a manifest of the home folder?

Tags: files, archive

I want to create a file manifest (list of file/folder names, directory structure, and file metadata) of my home folder. I do not want the actual content of the files to be saved.

How can this be done (preferrably without the terminal)?

Comment: Furious, does this edit reflect what you want?

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1: Metadata only [Edit]

So according to somebody's recent edit you may only want to backup file system structure and metadata non-periodically. This can be done easily:

```sh
find /home/furioususer -ls
```

will list all files and directories in the directory `/home/furioususer` along with some metadata. To redirect the output to the file `/path/to/backups/file` use

```sh
find /home/furioususer -ls > /path/to/backups/file
```

You might want to give the file some meaningful name based on user name and time of backup:

```sh
find /home/furioususer -ls > "/path/to/backups/furioususer.metadata.$(date +%F_%T%z)"
```

`$(date +%F_%T%z)` tells the shell to execute the subcommand `date +%F_%T%z` and replace it by the output of that command. (Go ahead an try to run that command directly to see the result and toy with it!) The quotation marks are necessary to prevent most *special* characters (e. g. spaces and colons) like they appear in that date string from being misinterpreted. Of course you can choose any other (programmatically generated) file path you deem appropriate.

You can tune the data you're actually interested in (e. g. size, owner, group, permissions, mtime, atime) by substituting `-ls` with `-printf <YOUR FORMAT STRING>`. For details on that option look up [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html). Example with file path, file size, owner, access permissions and last time of modification:

```sh
find /home/furioususer -printf "%p: %s bytes, owned by %u, permissions %m, last change %t\n"
```

Since this may become quite large yet well compressible, you can pipe that through a compressor like `xz`:

```sh
find /home/furioususer -ls | xz > "/path/to/backups/furioususer.metadata.$(date +%F_%T%z).xz"
```

You can generalise this command a little by using environment variables (of the form `${}`) instead of hard-coding your home path and user name, that the shell will then substitute with their respective values:

```sh
find "${HOME}" -ls | xz > "/path/to/backups/${USER}.metadata.$(date +%F_%T%z).xz"
```

Restoring from this automatically is quite another story, but I don't know how this would be of any use as you'd be pretty much dead in the water without actual file data.

If you don't want to fiddle with the command line every time, you can create a shell script using a graphical text editor and an application starter pointing to it with an application starter editor.

## Solution 2: [Déjà-Dup](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup)

… offers various backup options – offline and online – some of which seem to suit your needs. It's also well integrated with Nautilus, so you can easily review and restore previous versions of files. I never tried it personally but I researched its possibilities intensely a while ago.

## Solution 3: Copy-on-write snaphots

The most flexible and resource saving (offline) solution I know for this is to put your home directory on a [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) volume¹ and perform periodic [snapshots](https://lwn.net/Articles/579009/) of it. The last time I looked (about 1 year ago) there was no off-the-shelf tool to do this and I invested a couple of afternoons in modifying, tweaking and testing other people's shell scripts to make them work the way I want.

The whole deployment can technically be done without touching the command line yourself if you reuse existing work, but due to the experimental state of things you'll likely reach points where it would be a lot easier to do so. Therefore I expect this to be no suitable solution for you but it may be for other people.

If asked to, I will provide code, instructions and links for working solutions including my own.

¹ ext3/4 can be converted to Btrfs without trouble

Comment: David, can you please combine your two answers? Thanks!

Comment: @Whaaaaaat: Yes, but wouldn't it be better to have fundamentally different approaches as separate answers?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You should always try to keep one answer/question. Make it into different methods. Like Method 1 being btrfs and Method 2 being Deja-Dup.

Comment: Thanks! Does this back up permissions as well?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat It should. The `-ls` command to `find` is like `ls -l` -it lists permissions among other things.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Wonderful! +1 for you!

Comment: Solution 3 is what I am after. But I am new ubuntu-user so I don't understand the command you have written (after some attempts). Please clarify what I should exactly write in terminal.

Comment: I added more explanation.

Comment: David, I appreciate your effort but I am very disappointed in your lack of pedagogy. I repeat: I am a new user.

Suggestions:
-Remove the apostrophes. Seeing all these odd characters, I actually wonder if it's part of the command too. It's unnecessary anyway when you highlight - you are destroying the clean look (simplification) a highlight gives it, and confuse new users such as myself in the process.

-don't overcomplicate things with the searchpath. Write an example of searchpath in the homefolder where I can try&succeed. It will be easier to take it from there and modify to desired path.

Comment: And to answer your repeated thought about what use this will have without the actual data. It's pretty simple: let's say I have a folder of 100 popular big video files. If the HD crashes I will use the metadata to track down and download the files again. Backup popular data (which you can download whenever wherever) is meaningless, especially when you can't or don't want to sacrifice HD storage.

Comment: I actually use a similar backup strategy for some of my files and wanted to point out that there's no straight forward solution for an automated restoration. As for the pedagogy: I was waiting for specific questions like the one above to not waste my effort on things that don't need explaining. I'll go more in detail in another edit.